# Better way to restrict RDP via NSG

Tags: azure

Bit new to Azure, was able to make a Powershell script to create a VM.

```
# $MyPublicIP = (Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://ifconfig.me/ip").Content
$MyPublicIP = $(Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -PrefixOrigin Dhcp).IPAddress

Write-Host "Creating network security group, that can be only accessed from my public IP address - '$MyPublicIP'"

$nsgRuleRDP = New-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig `
     -Name "$NSGRuleName-RDP"  `
     -Description "Open RDP"  `
     -Protocol Tcp `
     -Direction Inbound `
     -Priority 1000 `
     -SourceAddressPrefix $MyPublicIP `
     -SourcePortRange * `
     -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
     -DestinationPortRange 3389 `
     -Access Allow
```

But the issue is `$MyPublicIP` is my local computer IP address (only on our company network), and my public facing one comes from the VPN provider my company uses. I am not sure how to programmatically get the IP address of my VPN provider. I can manually copy it from https://www.whatismyip.com/

And even if I was able to figure out how to fetch my public facing IP address, it seems to change frequently and I am finding myself updating the RDP rule on NSG.

Anyone know if there is a better way to restrict access? Like some sort of AD group? I am not sure of the right terminology for this in Azure land. TIA

Answer (score 2):

> I am not sure how to programmatically get the IP address of my VPN provider. I can manually copy it from https://www.whatismyip.com/

You can use the below **PowerShell** script to get your **Public IP** without copying it manually.

```
#IPV4 Public IP 
$ipApiUrl = "https://api.ipify.org?format=json"
$publicIpResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ipApiUrl
$publicIpAddress = $publicIpResponse.ip
Write-Host "Public IPv4 Address: $publicIpAddress"

Write-Host "Creating network security group, that can be only accessed from my public IP address :$publicIpAddress"

Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -Name "NRMS-tut2qoxap3z3yv-venkal-Mindtree-vnet" -ResourceGroupName "v-venkal-Mindtree" | 
    Add-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name rdp-rule -Description "Allow RDP" -Access `
        Allow -Protocol Tcp -Direction Inbound -Priority 100 -SourceAddressPrefix $publicIpAddress  `
        -SourcePortRange * -DestinationAddressPrefix * -DestinationPortRange 3389 |
        Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup
```

**Output:**

[image]

> And even if I was able to figure out how to fetch my public facing IP address, it seems to change frequently and I am finding myself updating the RDP rule on NSG.

If your public IP frequently changes, that will impact your VM connectivity. There are ways to connect to your VM without a public IP, such as using **Azure Bastion**, or you can check with your company network to provide a list of VPN network public IPs to whitelist them in NSG rules

If your company uses a **full tunnel** VPN, the network team will provide the public IP details of the VPN network. If using a **split tunnel** VPN, it should be a combination of the company VPN network and the broadband public IP. You need to whitelist both IPs to establish the connection. Sometimes, the broadband public IP may change automatically.

To address the challenge of a dynamic public IP address causing frequent updates to the `Network Security Group` rule, you can use **Azure Bastion**. It provides secure `RDP` and `SSH` access to your Azure VMs directly from the **Azure portal** without exposing the VMs to the public internet.

[image]

Reference: [Create an RDP connection to a Windows VM using Azure Bastion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/bastion-connect-vm-rdp-windows)

Comment: Thank you. Yea, checking with my IT to get the range instead. Bastion seems a very good idea, but the price is killing it. Don't think I'll get the approval for it. Do you know if there's some sort of "security group" kind of a thing, where people will be added and everyone in the group will have access to the NSG

Comment: If your VM is joined to Azure Ad, you can assign the role  to the group,so that who ever in the group they can only login to the VM,buy you can not allow the Azure Ad group in NSG.

Comment: Hi @scorpion35, Let me know if this has helped to resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi @venkatV Found out another solution that is better suited for us. Using the CIDR ranges our VPN uses - which works for anyone (only after connecting to our company VPN) and anyone can RDP into the VM (with the shared username/pwd). Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If you allow the VPN CIDR range IP addresses in the NSG, you will be able to connect to RDP from the VPN network. I hope my answer is helpful in resolving your query

Comment: Indeed. That is idea, only to be able to RDP while connected on company VPN. Your answer is definitely helpful. Thank you :)